# How to enable CONFIG_NETFILTER_XT_MATCH_IPVS for Docker in CentOS 7?

Tags: docker, centos7

When I run wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/docker/docker/master/contrib/check-config.sh
a tool, for checking for Docker configuration errors, I get an error saying `CONFIG_NETFILTER_XT_MATCH_IPVS` is missing. How can I install / enable this in CentOS 7?

```
./check-config.sh
info: reading kernel config from /proc/config.gz ...

Generally Necessary:
- cgroup hierarchy: properly mounted [/sys/fs/cgroup]
- CONFIG_NAMESPACES: enabled
- CONFIG_NET_NS: enabled
- CONFIG_PID_NS: enabled
- CONFIG_IPC_NS: enabled
- CONFIG_UTS_NS: enabled
- CONFIG_CGROUPS: enabled
- CONFIG_CGROUP_CPUACCT: enabled
- CONFIG_CGROUP_DEVICE: enabled
- CONFIG_CGROUP_FREEZER: enabled
- CONFIG_CGROUP_SCHED: enabled
- CONFIG_CPUSETS: enabled
- CONFIG_MEMCG: enabled
- CONFIG_KEYS: enabled
- CONFIG_VETH: enabled
- CONFIG_BRIDGE: enabled
- CONFIG_BRIDGE_NETFILTER: enabled
- CONFIG_NF_NAT_IPV4: enabled
- CONFIG_IP_NF_FILTER: enabled
- CONFIG_IP_NF_TARGET_MASQUERADE: enabled
- CONFIG_NETFILTER_XT_MATCH_ADDRTYPE: enabled
- CONFIG_NETFILTER_XT_MATCH_CONNTRACK: enabled
- CONFIG_NETFILTER_XT_MATCH_IPVS: missing
- CONFIG_IP_NF_NAT: enabled
- CONFIG_NF_NAT: enabled
- CONFIG_NF_NAT_NEEDED: enabled
- CONFIG_POSIX_MQUEUE: enabled
```

Comment: It's already included in the kernel shipped with CentOS 7. What is different about your system? You don't appear to be using the standard kernel.

Comment: It's a Linode 2GB system (https://www.linode.com/pricing) with CentOS 7.3 They might have some sort of custom kernel. I'll look into it. Tx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The kernel config you want is already present in the distribution-supplied kernels in CentOS 7.

As you mentioned, you're using Linode, so you are likely also using Linode's supplied kernel instead of the standard kernel. You just need to [switch back to the distribution kernel](https://www.linode.com/docs/tools-reference/custom-kernels-distros/run-a-distribution-supplied-kernel-with-kvm).